# GST RTP stream in python - problem with linking rtpbin element

Tags: python, gstreamer, rtp

I am trying to learn gst in python and am trying to make a simple rtp video sender and receiver with rtpbin, but when I connect the rtpbin to udpsink, nothing works. What am I missing.

This is the sender

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst, GObject

import signal
import sys

# Initialize GStreamer
Gst.init(None)

# Create pipeline elements
pipeline = Gst.Pipeline.new("my-pipeline")
src = Gst.ElementFactory.make("videotestsrc", "video-source")
encoder = Gst.ElementFactory.make("x264enc", "video-encoder")
payloader = Gst.ElementFactory.make("rtph264pay", "payloader")
rtpbin = Gst.ElementFactory.make("rtpbin", "rtpbin")
udpsink = Gst.ElementFactory.make("udpsink", "udpsink")

# Set properties for elements as needed
src.set_property("is_live", True)
src.set_property("pattern", 0)
udpsink.set_property("host", "127.0.0.1")
udpsink.set_property("port", 5000)

# Add elements to the pipeline
pipeline.add(src)
pipeline.add(encoder)
pipeline.add(payloader)
pipeline.add(rtpbin)
pipeline.add(udpsink)

# Link the elements together
src.link(encoder)
encoder.link(payloader)
payloader.link(rtpbin)
rtpbin.link(udpsink)

def handle_interrupt(sig, frame):
    pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
    Gst.deinit()
    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handle_interrupt)

# Start the pipeline
pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

# Start the GObject main loop
GObject.MainLoop().run()
```

and this is the receiver:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst, GObject

# Initialize Gstreamer
Gst.init(None)

# Create pipeline
pipeline = Gst.Pipeline.new("rtp_pipeline")

# Create elements
udpsrc = Gst.ElementFactory.make("udpsrc", "udpsrc")
rtph264depay = Gst.ElementFactory.make("rtph264depay", "rtph264depay")
avdec_h264 = Gst.ElementFactory.make("avdec_h264", "avdec_h264")
timeoverlay = Gst.ElementFactory.make("timeoverlay", "timeoverlay")
videoconvert = Gst.ElementFactory.make("videoconvert", "videoconvert")
autovideosink = Gst.ElementFactory.make("autovideosink", "autovideosink")

rtpbin = Gst.ElementFactory.make("rtpbin", "rtpbin")


# Set properties
udpsrc.set_property("port", 5000)
udpsrc.set_property("caps", Gst.caps_from_string("application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264"))
timeoverlay.set_property("halignment", 0)
timeoverlay.set_property("valignment", 0)
timeoverlay.set_property("shaded-background", True)
timeoverlay.set_property("font-desc", "Sans 24")
timeoverlay.set_property("time-mode", "running-time")

# Add elements to pipeline
pipeline.add(udpsrc)
pipeline.add(rtph264depay)
pipeline.add(avdec_h264)
pipeline.add(timeoverlay)
pipeline.add(videoconvert)
pipeline.add(autovideosink)

# Link elements
udpsrc.link(rtph264depay)
rtph264depay.link(avdec_h264)
avdec_h264.link(timeoverlay)
timeoverlay.link(videoconvert)
videoconvert.link(autovideosink)

# Start pipeline
pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

# Start the GTK main loop
GObject.MainLoop().run()
```

What am I missing, and how to fix it?

If I link elements in sender without rtpbin, everything works:

```
# Link the elements together
src.link(encoder)
encoder.link(payloader)
payloader.link(udpsink)
```

But I want to use rtpbin for further experimenting and playing around. How to properly connect rtpbin?

Answer (score -1):

rtpbin has "sometime" src pads.
To link some time pad "pad-added" signal shall be registered.
Similar to the decodebin.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).